# How to manually get/set object model from AngularDart component?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Angular manages our objects somewhere in the Scope, but I need to manually set and get the object that controls a component so I can automatically set all the component's info once I download its model from the web through JSON.

**Example**

```dart
@Component (selector: 'my-component')
class MyComponent {
    //component fields
}
```

As the user interacts with `<my-component>` it changes its **fields**. I want to be able to get the whole MyComponent object with its fields to save them like this

```dart
MyComponent comp = magicComponentGetterFunc('my-component');
String json = encodeJson (comp); //I do this this redstone_mapper
```

Comment: Can you please add more details (some code) about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer see new example :)

Comment: So you wan't to search the DOM and then get the component class instance from the DOM element. There was a method in earlier Angular classes but only for testing purposes, not for production, I'm not sure whether this is fully supported in Angular.dart 1.0 but I think this was added with one of the recent versions. Doing this is usually an indication that you are using Angular the wrong way though.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ngProbe` can do that.

```
ElementProbe ep = ngProbe('my-component');
```

You can can find examples by visiting the links at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular where `ngProbe` or `ElementProbe` is mentioned.

The CHANGELOG.md mentions that `ngProbe` is necessary for animation but the codedoc on the `ElementProbe` class still states that it is for testing and debugging (see https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/96c0bcc7b6b0c3501b2c4799f425de8cd2e4dc0c/lib/core_dom/view_factory.dart#L259)

To get the JSON you either have to implement a getter/method (for example `toJson`) that returns the JSON you want or use some of the available serialization solutions (see [State of Serialization and Deserialization of JSON in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135876)).

If you want to do that this usually indicates that your approach works against the way Angular should be used.